# Cannot assign a value to final variable 'paramView'

Tags: android, settext

I have an error at Android Studio. My paramView is red and i don't know why here is my code: The error is at the big marked code.

```
    public void plusOne(final View paramView)
    {
        Object localObject;
        if (this.scoreInteger == 0)
        {
            localObject = new Timer();
            this.timerTask = new TimerTask()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    paramView.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            ((TextView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(MainActivity.this.myTimer + "");
                            MainActivity localMyActivity = MainActivity.this;
                            localMyActivity.myTimer += 1;
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            ((Timer)localObject).schedule(this.timerTask, 0L, 10L);
        }
        this.scoreInteger += 1;
        if (this.scoreInteger < 10)
        {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.highScore)).setText(String.valueOf(this.scoreInteger));
            return;
        }
        this.timerTask.cancel();
        this.timerTask = null;
        **paramView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.plusOne);
        paramView.setText(String.valueOf(this.scoreInteger));**
        paramView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.reset)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        **paramView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);**
        if (this.myTimer < this.myHighScore)
        {
            this.myHighScore = this.myTimer;
            localObject = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", 0).edit();
            ((SharedPreferences.Editor)localObject).putInt("your_int_key", this.myHighScore);
            ((SharedPreferences.Editor)localObject).commit();
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            paramView.**setText**(this.highScoreString + String.valueOf(this.myHighScore));
            paramView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return;
            this.myHighScore = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", 0).getInt("your_int_key", 0);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to solve that Problem. I can't finish the app. Thank You

Comment: If it's declared as **final**, then it's a **constant**, not a **variable**. Meaning that you can't change it, once set.

Comment: Why? Why do you dislike? I do not understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare paramView as final in your method parameters. You can't modify a final variable (that's why it's said to be final, actually).

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare a variable as final, you cannot change it.